# Is there functionality to generate a random character in Java?

Tags: java, random

Does Java have any functionality to generate random characters or strings?  Or must one simply pick a random integer and convert that integer's [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) code to a character?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but yes, it involves generating a random `int` (using e.g. [`java.util.Random.nextInt`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)) and then using that to map to a `char`. If you have a specific alphabet, then something like this is nifty:

```
    import java.util.Random;

    //...

    Random r = new Random();

    String alphabet = "123xyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        System.out.println(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
    } // prints 50 random characters from alphabet
```

---

Do note that `java.util.Random` is actually a [*pseudo*-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) based on the rather weak [linear congruence formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). You mentioned the need for cryptography; you may want to investigate the use of a much stronger [cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) in that case (e.g. [`java.security.SecureRandom`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)).

Comment: Thanks, that actually is a concise solution if you want generate a defined set of characters. 
For the whole alphabet [dogbane's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2627801/1845976) is a bit shorter.
You could increase efficiency and readability a bit by using arrays. See my [hex example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20345686/1845976).

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm using this, however since I'm a noob, could someone explain to me what (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) does exactly?

Answer (score 151):

To generate a random char in a-z:

```
Random r = new Random();
char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

Comment: You can even go further and `(char)(r.nextInt('z' - 'a') + 'a')` if you're not sure how many letters are in the alphabet.

Comment: @AmirEldor that will never produce a z, because `'z' - 'a' == 25`, not 26.

Answer (score 88):

You could also use the RandomStringUtils from the [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) project:

Dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Usages:

```java
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(stringLength);
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(stringLength);
```

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 16):

```
private static char rndChar () {
    int rnd = (int) (Math.random() * 52); // or use Random or whatever
    char base = (rnd < 26) ? 'A' : 'a';
    return (char) (base + rnd % 26);

}
```

Generates values in the ranges a-z, A-Z.

Comment: How exactly does `(char) (base + rnd % 26)` work? Is it because adding a char to an int converts the char into its ASCII number?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - Yep that's why. Each `char` is also implicitly convertible to an int, so 'a' can be treated as an integer value (97), and then offsetting by say 3 will yield 100 which when converted back to a `char` is 'd'.

Answer (score 13):

```
String abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

char letter = abc.charAt(rd.nextInt(abc.length()));
```

This one works as well.

Comment: Nice idea to set possible characters before.

Answer (score 3):

In the following 97 is the ASCII value of small "a".

```
public static char randomSeriesForThreeCharacter() {
    Random r = new Random();
    char random_3_Char = (char) (97 + r.nextInt(3));
    return random_3_Char;
}
```

In the above, 3 is the number for a, b, c or d and if you want all characters, like a to z, then you replace 3 number to 25.

Comment: This is close to incomprehensible. Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14021385/edit)? (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 1):

You could use generators from the [Quickcheck specification-based test framework](https://quickcheck.dev.java.net/).

To create a random string use [anyString](https://quickcheck.dev.java.net/javadoc/net/java/quickcheck/generator/PrimitiveGeneratorSamples.html#anyString%28%29) method.

```
String x = anyString();
```

You could create strings from a more restricted set of characters or with min/max size restrictions.

Normally you would run tests with multiple values:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
  for (List<Integer> any : someLists(integers())) {
    //A test executed with integer lists
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar):

```
Iterable<Character> chars = $('a', 'z'); // 'a', 'b', c, d .. z
```

Given `chars`, you can build a "shuffled" range of characters:

```
Iterable<Character> shuffledChars = $('a', 'z').shuffle();
```

Then taking the first `n` characters, you get a random string of length `n`. The final code is simply:

```
public String randomString(int n) {
    return $('a', 'z').shuffle().slice(n).toString();
}
```

**NB**: the condition `n > 0` is checked by `slice`.

As Steve correctly pointed out, `randomString` uses at most once each letter. As workaround, you can repeat the alphabet `m` times before call `shuffle`:

```
public String randomStringWithRepetitions(int n) {
    return $('a', 'z').repeat(10).shuffle().slice(n).toString();
}
```

Or just provide your alphabet as `String`:

```
public String randomStringFromAlphabet(String alphabet, int n) {
    return $(alphabet).shuffle().slice(n).toString();
}

String s = randomStringFromAlphabet("00001111", 4);
```

Comment: This will use each character at most once in the random string. This may not be what the OP needs.

Comment: @Steve: thanks, I've fixed my answer and extended the library http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/changeset/4c26ccf9464e/

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple but useful discovery. It defines a class named **RandomCharacter** with 5 overloaded methods to get a certain type of character randomly. You can use these methods in your future projects.

```
    public class RandomCharacter {
    /** Generate a random character between ch1 and ch2 */
    public static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2) {
        return (char) (ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 - ch1 + 1));
    }

    /** Generate a random lowercase letter */
    public static char getRandomLowerCaseLetter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
    }

    /** Generate a random uppercase letter */
    public static char getRandomUpperCaseLetter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('A', 'Z');
    }

    /** Generate a random digit character */
    public static char getRandomDigitCharacter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('0', '9');
    }

    /** Generate a random character */
    public static char getRandomCharacter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('\u0000', '\uFFFF');
    }
}
```

To demonstrate how it works let's have a look at the following test program displaying 175 random lowercase letters.

```
public class TestRandomCharacter {
    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUMBER_OF_CHARS = 175;
        final int CHARS_PER_LINE = 25;
        // Print random characters between 'a' and 'z', 25 chars per line
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHARS; i++) {
            char ch = RandomCharacter.getRandomLowerCaseLetter();
            if ((i + 1) % CHARS_PER_LINE == 0)
                System.out.println(ch);
            else
                System.out.print(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is:

[image]

if you run one more time again:

[image]

I am giving credit to **Y.Daniel Liang** for his book [Introduction to Java Programming, Comprehensive Version, 10th Edition,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133761312) where I cited this knowledge from and use in my projects.

**Note**: If you are unfamiliar with overloaded methhods, in a nutshell Method Overloading is a feature that allows a class to have more than one method having the same name, if their argument lists are different.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Java [Randomizer](http://docs.huihoo.com/javadoc/liferay/4.2/util-java/com/liferay/util/Randomizer.html) class.
I think you can randomize a character using the randomize(char[] array) method.

Comment: @manuel, I think then we need to install the Liefra jar file, it doesnot come with the default one

Answer (score 0):

[polygenelubricants' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626989/1845976) is also a good solution if you only want to generate hexadecimal values:

```
/** A list of all valid hexadecimal characters. */
private static char[] HEX_VALUES = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

/** Random number generator to be used to create random chars. */
private static Random RANDOM = new SecureRandom();

/**
 * Creates a number of random hexadecimal characters.
 *
 * @param nValues the amount of characters to generate
 *
 * @return an array containing <code>nValues</code> hex chars
 */
public static char[] createRandomHexValues(int nValues) {
    char[] ret = new char[nValues];
    for (int i = 0; i < nValues; i++) {
        ret[i] = HEX_VALUES[RANDOM.nextInt(HEX_VALUES.length)];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My propose for generating random string with mixed case like: **"DthJwMvsTyu"**.
This algorithm based on ASCII codes of letters when its codes `a-z` (97 to 122) and `A-Z` (65 to 90) differs in 5th bit (2^5 or 1 << 5 or 32).

`random.nextInt(2)`: result is 0 or 1.

`random.nextInt(2) << 5`: result is 0 or 32.

Upper `A` is 65 and lower `a` is 97. Difference is only on 5th bit (32) so for generating random char we do binary OR '|' random `charCaseBit` (0 or 32) and random code from `A` to `Z` (65 to 90).

```
public String fastestRandomStringWithMixedCase(int length) {
    Random random = new Random();
    final int alphabetLength = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);
    while (result.length() < length) {
        final char charCaseBit = (char) (random.nextInt(2) << 5);
        result.append((char) (charCaseBit | ('A' + random.nextInt(alphabetLength))));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: please can you add more info for more understanding and clarity. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @PragatiSingh, yes, I edited comment and added some description.

Comment: @PragatiSingh Nuix8s 8m58On7

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to generate random alphanumeric code. First you have to declare a string of allowed characters what you want to include in random number.and also define max length of string

```
 SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
 String CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
    StringBuilder generatedString= new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM_LENGTH; i++) {
        int randonSequence = secureRandom .nextInt(CHARACTERS.length());
        generatedString.append(CHARACTERS.charAt(randonSequence));
    }
```

Use toString() method to get String from StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

In fact mentioned methods don't generate real random char. To generate real random char you should give it a random seed! in example time in millisecond. this code generate 10 random char and then Convert it to String:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main() {

     String randomKey;

    char[] tempArray={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};  //ten characters

    long seed=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Random random=new Random(seed);
    for (int aux=0; aux<10;aux++){

        tempArray[aux]=(char) random.nextInt(255);
        System.out.println(tempArray[aux]);
    }

    randomKey=String.copyValueOf(tempArray);  


      System.out.println(randomKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
char uppercaseChar = (char) ((int)(Math.random()*100)%26+65);

char lowercaseChar = (char) ((int)(Math.random()*1000)%26+97);
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Random` is the more effective one I have tried out so far, having a precision of **98.65%** uniqueness.
I have provided bellow some tests which generate 10000 batches of a hundred 2 alphanumeric chars strings and calculates the average.

Other random tools were `RandomStringUtils` from commons.lang3 and `java.util.Math`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int unitPrintMarksTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        unitPrintMarksTotal += generateBatchOfUniquePrintMarks(i);
    }

    System.out.println("The precision across 10000 runs with 100 item batches is: " + (float) unitPrintMarksTotal / 10000);
}

private static int generateBatchOfUniquePrintMarks(int batch) {
    Set<String> printMarks = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printMarks.add(generatePrintMarkWithJavaUtil());
    }

    System.out.println("Batch " + batch + " Unique number of elements is " + printMarks.size());

    return printMarks.size();
}

// the best so far => 98.65
// with 3 chars => 99.98
// with 4 chars => 99.9997
private static String generatePrintMarkWithJavaUtil() {
    int leftLimit = 48; // numeral '0'
    int rightLimit = 122; // letter 'z'
    int targetStringLength = 2;
    String printMark;
    do {
        printMark = new Random().ints(leftLimit, rightLimit + 1)
                .filter(i -> (i <= 57 || i >= 65) && (i <= 90 || i >= 97))
                .limit(targetStringLength)
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();
    } while (!isValid(printMark));

    return printMark;
}

// 95.46
private static String generatePrintMarkWithCommonsLang3() {
    String printMark;
    do {
        printMark = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(2).toUpperCase();
    } while (!isValid(printMark));

    return printMark;
}

// 95.92
private static String generatePrintMarkWithMathRandom() {
    final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    StringBuilder printMark;
    do {
        printMark = new StringBuilder();
        int i = (int) (Math.random() * ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());
        printMark.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(i));
        int j = (int) (Math.random() * ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());
        printMark.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(j));
    } while (!isValid(printMark.toString()));

    return printMark.toString();
}

private static boolean isValid(final String printMark) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getRandomNumberOfString(int number) {
        Random r = new Random();
        String randomString = "";
        String randomValue = "123456789 $#^&*()!~ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            randomString = randomString + randomValue.charAt(r.nextInt(randomValue.length()));
        }
        System.out.println("Length"+  randomString.length());
        System.out.println("String "+  randomString);
        return randomString;
}


getRandomNumberOfString(2000);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted, highest voted and my other answers only generate a subset of the normal printable chars. Several support a user-defined set of chars which is nice. But I simply want any printable chars. My code answer is based on various answers here.

It does not include another lib. Doesn't seem worth it to do this rather simple task.

It picks chars in the range 0x20 (space) inclusive to del (0x7f) exclusive which covers upper&lower a-z, digits and symbols.

Generates a string of specified length.

Using char[] as Jon Skeet says. Always do as he suggests :)

Hopefully, no off by one errors :) ... IMO odd that nextInt is *exclusive* for the upper bound.

Not sure whether it matters, but declared random outside method. Yes, seeding would be good, but for my purposes pseudo-random is good enough. You can seed if you want.

Not generated by chatpgt ... maybe it can learn something from me :)

```
private final Random random = new Random();

private String getRandomString(int length) {
    final char startCode = 0x20; // space
    final char endCode =  0x7F; // del
    final char codeCount = endCode - startCode;
    var chars = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        final char codeOffset = (char) random.nextInt(codeCount + 1);
        final char code = (char) (codeOffset + startCode);
        chars[i] = code;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind adding a new library in your code you can generate characters with [MockNeat](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat) (disclaimer: I am one of the authors).

```
MockNeat mock = MockNeat.threadLocal();

Character chr = mock.chars().val();
Character lowerLetter = mock.chars().lowerLetters().val();
Character upperLetter = mock.chars().upperLetters().val();
Character digit = mock.chars().digits().val();
Character hex = mock.chars().hex().val();
```

Comment: a whole library to simple get a random char?

Comment: @RafaelLima the library is making more than that.

Comment: The library "may" be able to do a lot more than that, but you suggested a  person to add a new dependency to his project just to get a random char... it makes no sense for a thousand reasons.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void  main(String[] args) {

  //  System.out.println("Enter a number to changeit at char  ");
    Random random = new Random();

    int x = random.nextInt(26)+65;    //0  to 25
    System.out.println((char)x);
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?

Comment: an alphabet ascii code for Char A is 25 and go ahed , first line of the code generate a random number between 25 and 90 and second line gona cast that number to char for example if it generate 25 second line convert it to A .

Answer (score -1):

I simply want to tell you to use UUID.randomUUID() and toString() as its simplest way i also used

Answer (score -2):

```
   Random randomGenerator = new Random();

   int i = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
   System.out.println((char)i);
```

Should take care of what you want, assuming you consider '0,'1','2'.. as characters.

Comment: This is most likely not what was intended, because in that range you include a whole number of control characters which are very unlikely to be expected.