# Randomly generate test data in Java using UUID

Tags: java, uuid

I want to add sample test data to my NoteTableModel.

Currently I have it set up like this:

```
public void buildTestNoteTable(){

    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,10);
    //System.out.println(uuid);


    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
        EssayNote newNote = new EssayNote(i, 20131105, "New Test note" +i, uuid);
        noteTableData.add(newNote); 
    }  
}
```

What I want to do is to have it so that the section that says "Blah Blah Blah" is randomly generated letters with a length of 10. How should I update my current method to be able to do this ?

EDIT: I updated the code using UUID. I replaced the hard coded "Blah Blah Blah" with the uuid and I am now getting a random serial number but I am getting the same number for every instance of note, which I do not want. How can I make it so that every EssayNote has a different UUID ?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626835/is-there-functionality-to-generate-a-random-character-in-java

Comment: You should be using property based testing (quickcheck).

Comment: What properties must the random text have? Must it be split into words? Must they be words of a particular language?

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache commons RandomStringUtils.random(10) :
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use UUID.
In order to use it you should import

```
import java.util.UUID;
```

Then in your code you can call

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,10);
System.out.println("uuid = " + uuid);
```

Hope this code will help you

**OR**
You can use custom method

```
String characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int length = 10;
public String generateString(){
    char[] randText = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        randText[i] = characters.charAt(Math.random()*length);
    }
    return new String(randText);
}
```

I haven't compiled this piece of code, but it should work properly

Comment: I used the first strategy with the UUID and it generated a random string but it's the same string for every single Note that I have. I updated my code above so you can see what I am working with. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should put : String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,10); inside of a for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate some numbers with the Java Random function, between 64-91, and treat them as ASCII characters. Wich will give you random characters