# How to generate a random char array of a specific length using specific characters

Tags: java, arrays, random, char

I am trying to take this char array here:

```
char[] options = {'F','Z','P','E','N','T','L','C','D','O'};
```

and generate a new random char array of a specific length. Like this:

`char[] results ={'Z','E','L','C'...}` all the way up to a length of 70 characters long.  I've already tried to create a new char such as `char[] results = new char[70]` and then using a `for` loop to try to get this. But for some reason my  mind is blanking. Can anybody refresh me? Thanks all

Comment: That doesn't look like Javascript, it looks like Java.

Comment: Might take a look at using this https://lodash.com/docs#sampleSize
Or look at the source if you want to roll your own solution

Comment: @Legumebo_Magezfeld lodash is for Javascript, his question is about Java. He got the tag wrong.

Comment: Please post code showing what you have tried.

Comment: Did you try looking at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626835/is-there-functionality-to-generate-a-random-character-in-java/2627801#2627801

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of straightforward solution

```
char[] options = {'F','Z','P','E','N','T','L','C','D','O'};
char[] result = new char[70];
Random r=new Random();
for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    result[i]=options[r.nextInt(options.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private static char[] options = {'F','Z','P','E','N','T','L','C','D','O'};

public static char[] createRandomArray() {
    Random r = new Random();

    char[] arr = new char[70];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = options[r.nextInt(options.length)];
    }
    return  arr;
}
```