# Java: Generate random letter, return as a String

Tags: java, string, random, char

I need to create a method to geneate random (single) letter and return it as **String**, not as a **char**.
I saw solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626835/is-there-functionality-to-generate-a-random-character-in-java) creating random char. But I need my method to return a String type.
I managed to build the following method:

```
public static String randomLetter(){
    int num = intInRange(0, 26) + 97;
    char [] temp = new char[1];
    temp[0] = (char) num;
    return new String(temp);
}
```

Based on already existing method in our project

```
public static int intInRange(int min, int max) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return rnd.nextInt(max - min) + min;
}
```

But I do not like what I currently have since I'm creating too many temporary variables to achieve the goal.
Is there a way to get similar result in a shorter way to avoid usage of `char [] temp` ?

Comment: Is using `intInRange()` an absolute must? Is selecting from a prefilled array of strings an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this. First cast the returned int as a `char` and then append `""` to convert to a String.

```
public static String randomLetter() { 
   return (char)(intInRange('a', 'z'+1)) +"";
}
```

Since `String.valueOf()` first boxes the char to Character and then calls `String.valueOf()` on that object, I would just call `Character.toString()` directly and avoid the extra overhead.

```
public static String randomLetter() {
    return  Character.toString(intInRange('a', 'z'+1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the solution suggested by  
@0x150 is clearer. Satyajit Bhatt detailized that. +1

Comment: @Prophet, read my updated answer.  Just use Character.toString();

Comment: Well, this sound even better, I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To be honest, the delta on overhead is there but negligible so any of the answers, imho, are acceptable.

Comment: Agree with you again :)

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be more useful to be able to return a `String` of *any* length, including 1? If so, you could do something like the following:

```
public static String randomString(int length) {
    return new Random().
        ints('A', 'z').
        filter(Character::isLetter).
        limit(length).
        collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).
        toString();
}
```